How to convert two floating voltages into two differential signals centered around a constant mode voltage without a fully differential opamp?
Suppose I have two voltages \$V_{\mathrm{in} +}\$ and \$V_{\mathrm{in} -}\$ that can
take any value from \$0\$ to \$V_{\mathrm{DD}}\$. I would like to use these voltages
(\$V_{\mathrm{in} +}\$ and \$V_{\mathrm{in} -}\$) to produce two new voltages
\$V_{\mathrm{out} +} = V_{\mathrm{out}, \mathrm{CM}} + \frac{1}{2} (V_{\mathrm{in} +} -
V_{\mathrm{in} -})\$ and \$V_{\mathrm{out} -} = V_{\mathrm{out}, \mathrm{CM}} -
\frac{1}{2} (V_{\mathrm{in} +} - V_{\mathrm{in} -})\$. This seems exactly the sort
of thing a fully differential opamp is designed for. However, the input range
with a fully differential opamp is limited and also a fully differential opamp
requires a CMFB to work which makes the whole thing power hungry. Is there a way to do this that does not require the use of an fully differential opamp and where the output common mode voltage can be easily defined?
EDIT: I am looking for an integrated circuit solution.

If the differential signal is purely AC, you could use a transformer.

@ThePhoton, Thanks for your reply. I forgot to indicate that I'm looking for an integrated circuit solution.

you should update your question to include this requirement. You might also want to specify the frequency band (both upper and lower limit) that the differential and common-mode paths must cover, and the range of voltages of the inputs (Vin+, Vin- and Vout,cm).

Also specify the maximum power consumption you can accept (i.e. quantify what you mean by "power hungry").

Why do you need an IC solution? There are transformers that would be perfect for the job, cost very little, and take very little space--look into using ethernet magnetics.

@Hearth, because I am building an integrated circuit.

That would probably be a good idea to actually mention. A transformer still might not be out of the question but probably isn't the way to go, then.

As @The Photon has already pointed out, a transformer (1/1:1) should be useful.
Adjust Vcm (V3) as needed.


Thanks for your reply. I forgot to indicate that I'm looking for an integrated circuit solution.
